# Prestashop login error: "Details: Error thrown: [object Object]"

Tags: authentication, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

In Prestashop backend login page, when I try to login I get the following message:

```
TECHNICAL ERROR:
    Details: Error thrown: [object Object]
    Text status: parsererror
```

Screen Picture:
[image]

Comment: Have you solved then?

Answer (score 3):

When the admin login form is submitted an ajax request is sent to the server, please take a look at the response of that ajax request after enabling error debugging, there must be an error shown there. Share the details of that error with us so that we guide you better.

FYI, to enable error debugging in PrestaShop you can follow the steps below.

- open file: config/defines.inc.php  (using FTP or hosting control panel)
- change false-->true:
  define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
  define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);